# Existence and uniquness are dual problems

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm learning PDE and know that the best way to solve the existence of a PDE problem is to figure out the uniqueness of its dual problem. It's said that the proof of this belongs to functional analysis, but I haven't found it. I tried to prove it myself but failed in one side. It needs **Hahn-Banach Theorem** reputedly. I'm appreciated if someone can help me with an answer or a reference. I prefer an answer better.

In detail:

$H$ is a Hilbert space. For a continuous linear operator $A:H\rightarrow H,$ the exsitence of problem: $$Ax=b, \quad \forall b\in H,$$
is equivalent with the uniquness of problem:
$$A^*y=0,$$
i.e. $y=0$ is the only solution of it.

Exsitence $\Rightarrow$ Uniquness: For any $y$ satisfied that $A^*y=0,$ find $x$ such that $Ax=y$ by the exsitence assumed. We have the following:
$$
0=(x,A^*y)=(Ax,y)=(y,y) \,\Rightarrow\, y=0.
$$

Uniqueness $\Rightarrow$ Exsitence: The part I need help. One needs **Hahn-Banach Theorem** to prove it. I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Are you asking about the Fredholm alternative?

Comment: @CalvinKhor I don't know Fredholm alternative before. I've searched it now. I'm not sure whether that theorem can help to solve this question. I think not. I'm appreciated if you can write an answer to connect Fredholm alternative with this question.

Comment: Well, it doesn't answer the "in detail:" problem but I'm not sure if that's what you want to ask. Because in PDEs, usually the operator $A$ should have some derivative and hence is not continuous from the same space to itself. I have a bad connection at the moment but maybe check Evans (2nd ed.) Ch 6 Theorem 4. I don't recall how it is proved, and I don't know if it answers the question. But you reminded me of it.

Comment: What you claim is not true in this generality: The adjoint is injective if and only if $A$ has dense range (which, of course, is not the same as surjectivity). You would need that $A$ has closed image which, by the *closed range theorem* is equivalent to $A^*$ having closed image (which you used in the proposed proof in the answer below).

Comment: @Jochen Thanks a lot for pointing out *closed range theorem*. Now I understand why Fredholm alternative discusses about $I-A$ and required that $A$ is compact operator. Because in this case $I-A$ has closed image. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's the point.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenter points out, $A$ is needed to have closed range to ensure that $\operatorname{Im} A^*$ is closed.

If we want to find $x$ such that $Ax=b,$ it's sufficient to find $x$ satisfied that $$(Ax,y)=(b,y),\quad \forall y\in H.$$

$A^*:H\rightarrow B=\operatorname{Im} A^*$ is a continuous linear operator. It's injective as $A^*y=0$ only has zero solution. So we have $(A^*)^{-1}:B\rightarrow H$ as a continuous linear operator by **inverse operator theorem**.

Define a continuous linear function $l_b:B\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$:
$$l_b(v)=(b,(A^*)^{-1}v)=(b,u),$$
where $A^*u=v.$ By **Hahn-Banach Theorem**, we can extend $l_b$ to $\overline{l_b}:H\rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$ By **Riesz Representation Theorem**, we have $x\in H$ such that $\overline{l_b}(v)=(x,v).$ Then for any $y\in H:$
$$
\overline{l_b}(A^*y)=(b,y)=(x,A^*y)=(Ax,y).
$$
That means the $x\in H$ we've found exactly satified that $Ax=b.$

---

However, I still have some question: It seems that the key point is *inverse operator theorem* and *Riesz Representation Theorem*, not *Hahn-Banach Theorem* actually. Is it OK to remove *Hahn-Banach Theorem* in the proof? As $\operatorname{Im}A^*=B\subset H$ is also a Hilbert space, inherit the inner product of $H.$ So we can use *Riesz Representation Theorem* directly on $B$. In fact we only use $\overline{l_b}$ on $B$, so the extension is useless. Also, we can prove a incidental proposition that *the solution $x$ of $Ax=b$ is always in $\operatorname{Im A^*}$* by this way.